# Why r don't code factors in 0 and 1 like spss to calculate $r$ coefficient?

Tags: r, statistics, data-modeling, spss

In SPSS you can enter the data as 0 and 1, then points out that the data is nominal. Then you can calculate whatever you want, like Pearson or Spearman correlation. However in R, when you enter the data you have to specify that this data is a factor even it's numeric you have to specify it's a factor, then it will be treated as a string. Now when I use cor(), I don't work because it needs numeric input.

How do you overcome this?

An example is given below:

```
data(Titanic)
Titanic <- data.frame(Titanic) 
cor(Titanic$Sex, Titanic$Freq)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of what you mean.

Comment: You can just use `as.integer()` around your factorial variable so that it can be used in the calculation.

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos I have data called "dat" , it has 2 columns; gender and age. I want to calculate Pearson correlation for this data. Gender data is coded M and F. I want use cor to get a p-value

Comment: @hannes101 what if it's actually inputed in text, should I recode all the data again into numbers?!

Comment: Please show us some of the data, you can use `dput()` on a smaller subsample of 10 observations and show it to us.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: What do you want to do? Convert a factor variable to numeric? Numeric to factor?

Comment: I have updated the post with simple example @ANG

Comment: `cor()` takes two numeric vectors. Here `Titanic$Sex` is not numeric

Comment: In spss similar function works fine as the variable Sex will be stored as numeric with a type nominal

Comment: Brute force transforming categorical variable into numeric and calculating *correlation* is wrong. I would suggest using regression, for example: `lm(Freq ~ Sex, Titanic)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How do you overcome this?

Two ways:

1. Feed the data to `cor()` how the function expects you to:

```
data(Titanic)
Titanic <- data.frame(Titanic) 
cor(Titanic$Sex, Titanic$Freq) # Bad, Titanic$Sex is a factor, not numeric
# Error in cor(Titanic$Sex, Titanic$Freq) : 'x' must be numeric
cor(as.numeric(Titanic$Sex), Titanic$Freq) # Good, cor() expects numeric
# [1] -0.294397
```

If you don't want to have to type out `as.numeric`, you can just use `c()`:

```
cor(c(Titanic$Sex), Titanic$Freq)
# [1] -0.294397
```

2. If you don't want to have to do that all the time, you can just make your own `cor()` to do it for you:

```
cor <- function(x, y, ...) {
    if ( !is.numeric(x) ) {
        message("Converting x to numeric.")
        x <- as.numeric(x)
    }
    if ( !is.numeric(y) ) {
        message("Converting y to numeric.")
        y <- as.numeric(y)
    }
    return(stats::cor(x, y, ...))
}

data(Titanic)
Titanic <- data.frame(Titanic) 
cor(Titanic$Sex, Titanic$Freq)

# Converting x to numeric.
# [1] -0.294397
```

## Why won't R do things like SPSS?

1. It's different software. You may have built up certain assumptions or expectations working with one particular piece of software for some time, but you should lose the expectation that other software will, *or should*, work the same way.
2. R's way may be more appropriate. You can see some discussion in [PoGibas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286528/pogibas)'s comment, and on Cross Validated on [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/102800/184400).

Comment: Typical correlation metrics (a la Pearson, Spearman, Kendall) don't make sense for categorical data. From a statistical point of view, calculating a Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient between a categorical variable "turned numeric" and a continuous variable therefore makes no sense, and I would strongly advise against such a practice. There exist quite a few interesting posts on Cross Validated that discuss alternative approaches towards establishing a relationship between a categorical and continuous variable.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I agree, which is why I have a link to one such discussion from Cross Validated in point two on my second heading, as well as mentioned PoGibas comment to the question on the same issue